# Batching array repeating the last X values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a long array and I want to apply to batch. But furthermore, I want to introduce the last `X` values into the new batch.

Let's suppose I want batches of 10 values, and I want to repeat the last 2 values.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(9)
vals = np.random.randint(0, 9, 55)
```

Out: `[5 6 8 6 1 6 4 8 1 8 5 1 0 8 8 8 2 6 8 1 8 3 5 3 6 7 0 8 1 8 1 6 6 2 8 4 5 3 4 0 8 0 4 5 4 8 3 8 4 8 0 1 2 3 7]`

Then my goal is:

```
[5 6 8 6 1 6 4 8 1 8]
[1 8 5 1 0 8 8 8 2 6]
[2 6 8 1 8 3 5 3 6 7]
[6 7 0 8 1 8 1 6 6 2]
[6 2 8 4 5 3 4 0 8 0]
[8 0 4 5 4 8 3 8 4 8]
[4 8 0 1 2 3 7]
```

As you can see the last two values in one array, are the first two of the next one.

I'm trying to find the logic of this and I found the next one:

```
bs, ct = 10, 2 # ct = X in my question

print(vals[bs*0-0:bs*1-0])
print(vals[bs*1-2:bs*2-2])
print(vals[bs*2-4:bs*3-4])
print(vals[bs*3-6:bs*4-6])
print(vals[bs*4-8:bs*5-8])
print(vals[bs*5-10:bs*6-10])
print(vals[bs*6-12:bs*7-12])
```

Thus, I tried to create the loop but is not working, and I'm sure it has to be easier.

```
print(vals[0 : bs])
for i in range(1, math.ceil(len(vals)/bs)):
    print(vals[bs*i-2**i : bs*(i+1)-2**i])
```

I tried to the following:

```
# Without repeating values works ok but not my goal
for i in range(0, len(vals), bs):
    print(vals[i:i+bs])
```

```
for i in range(0, len(vals), bs):
    print(vals[i-ct:i+bs])
```

I'm trying a lot of combinations using `ct` and `bt` but always have some trouble. Can somebody help me, please? I know it has to be easier but I can't find the logic...

Exists some other option more directly without using for loops? Maybe `numpy`? I found `np.split` and I think maybe `np.reshape` can work but the problem is repeating the X values.

Thank you!

Comment: `[vals[i: i+10] for i in range(0, vals.size, 8)]`? Where `8 == (bs - ct)`

Comment: Can you write it as an answer? I will select it as solution and close it

Comment: Sure, in a minute.

Comment: @Cyttorak Are you sure a list comrehention solution is needed? Isn't there a native numpy solution for this?

Comment: @Gulzar There is, using as_strided, but it is a little dangerous. And other solutions would be memory expensive. I will try to include it in my answer.

Comment: @Cyttorak What do you mean by dangerous?

Comment: @Gulzar you can look at the docs (linked in my answer), and there are few other answers here in SO itself. As it generates a view into the array, it is possible to modify the array's internal structure, which could have catastrophic consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using slicing:

```
>>> bs, ct = 10, 2
>>> result = [vals[i: i+bs] for i in range(0, vals.size, (bs - ct))]
>>> result
[array([5, 6, 8, 6, 1, 6, 4, 8, 1, 8]),
 array([1, 8, 5, 1, 0, 8, 8, 8, 2, 6]),
 array([2, 6, 8, 1, 8, 3, 5, 3, 6, 7]),
 array([6, 7, 0, 8, 1, 8, 1, 6, 6, 2]),
 array([6, 2, 8, 4, 5, 3, 4, 0, 8, 0]),
 array([8, 0, 4, 5, 4, 8, 3, 8, 4, 8]),
 array([4, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 7])]
```

Something like this can be also achieved by `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`

```
>>> from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
>>> steps = vals.itemsize
>>> as_strided(
        vals, 
        shape=(math.ceil(vals.size/(bs -ct)), 10), 
        strides=(steps*(bs - ct), steps)
)
array([[  5,   6,   8,   6,   1,   6,   4,   8,   1,   8],
       [  1,   8,   5,   1,   0,   8,   8,   8,   2,   6],
       [  2,   6,   8,   1,   8,   3,   5,   3,   6,   7],
       [  6,   7,   0,   8,   1,   8,   1,   6,   6,   2],
       [  6,   2,   8,   4,   5,   3,   4,   0,   8,   0],
       [  8,   0,   4,   5,   4,   8,   3,   8,   4,   8],
       [  4,   8,   0,   1,   2,   3,   7, 121, 274,  34]])
```

As the last few values do not exist, there will be some garbage values. Nonetheless, `as_strided` should be avoided unless you know what you are doing and absolutely need it. See the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html).

A safer alternative has been introduced in [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view)

Comment: Never read those notes before! Now my inner hacker wants out!